# Passing arguments between concatenated BASH CLI commands

Tags: command-line, bash, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl -o "/home/smith/Original-Video.%(ext)s" https://whatever && ffmpeg -i /home/smith/Original-Video.YYY -filter:v fps=10 -b:v 368k -b:a 32k -c:a libopus -strict -2 /home/smith/Recoded-Video.mp4
```

How can the extension captured by youtube-dl with %(ext)s be passed to the subsequent (&&) ffmpeg command in a single BASH CLI statement ?

So that:

```
Original-Video.YYY = Original-Video.%(ext)s
```

or

```
Original-Video.YYY = Original-Video.mp4

Original-Video.YYY = Original-Video.mkv

Original-Video.YYY = Original-Video.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll have to find the newest video file and parse it.

Untested, but something like:

```sh
base=/home/smith/Original-Video
if youtube-dl -o "$base.%(ext)s" https://whatever; then
    newest=$(stat -c $'%Y\t%n' "$base".* | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f 2-)
    ext=${newest%%*.}
    new="/home/smith/Recoded-Video.$ext"
    ffmpeg -i "$newest" -filter:v fps=10 -b:v 368k -b:a 32k -c:a libopus -strict -2 "$new"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wan't to mess around with bash: I've written a [downloader](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader) that uses ffmpeg and yt-dl to achieve the best combination of video and audio. The streams can be simply dragged to its GUI

Adding my ppa you can install and update it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install ytdownloader
```