# How to specify the download location in youtube-dl

Tags: downloads, youtube-dl

How do I specify the location in my filesystem where I want to download a YouTube video with youtube-dl? I tried using the `-P` option in youtube-dl, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you don't know the URL of the video you want to download you can't use it, obviously. Nobody can help you with that. And there's `-p`but NOT `-P`: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/youtube-dl.1.html

Comment: I would recommend looking into `yt-dlp` as a replacement to `youtube-dl`.  `youtube-dl` has not been touched in years, and `yt-dlp` is a fork that is maintained.  It does support `-P` or `--paths` for specifying where files are to be downloaded to.

Comment: If you want to do it without using scripts see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1416115/906933) how to install a GUI for it. You can configure where yt-dl will place the downloaded files

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl doesn't have a set directory prefix option like the `-P` option in wget. The default download directory in youtube-dl is the current directory.

Change directories using `cd` to any directory, for example your Downloads directory, before you download a YouTube video from a YouTube URL which I named `URL` in this example.

```
cd ~/Downloads
youtube-dl -F URL # list the available video formats
youtube-dl -f 3-digit-video-format-code URL
```